# Acumatica mobile app

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to figure out how to use the Acumatica mobile app. I can log on without any problems but when I click on Expense Claims for example, I get a error 500. On a test store that we have in the same installation, it gives error 404. Is there any configuration that has to be done before the app can work? I have Acumatica version 5.1. I've looked at the results in the Request profiler but do not see any thing that could help. I have also been looking for any documentation on the mobile app, is there a framework development guide?

Answer (score 0):

error 505 usually means difference between version on Acumatica site and mobile app.

Please verify that you have installed LATEST version from store and use Latest version of Acumatica.

Please provide version of your mob App (android or iOS) and version of Acumatica site.

Comment: The Acumatica site is 5.10.0687 and the app version is android 5.2. We updated the site to 5.2, but it still gave us error 500. The weird thing was that when we logged on a test company, the app worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed latest version of Android app from http://play.google.com/ and connected to one of our test sites on 5.2 https://external.acumatica.com/Acumatica5/ to Demo company without any issues, i can open Expense Claims UI without issues.

Well, looks like it somehow related to network connection, first of all try to use HTTPS protocol instead of HTTPS

Also will be helpful if you provide url and credentials to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use some proxy to capture http traffic to figure out the reason, i'm using Fiddler for example